# How to set the Timeout for request and get the response code for HttpRequest in MvvmCross xamarin

Tags: c#, android, http, xamarin, xamarin.android

**Code I have constructed so for**:

```
 public class RestService : IRestService
    {
        public async Task<StellaData> GetStellConfigData()
        {
            try
            {   
                //Declare a Http client
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                //Add a Base URl
                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.MUrl);
                //Add the response type
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //Add the API
                var response =await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(Constants.mUrl));

                var myItems = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StellaData>(response);
                return myItems;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

---

**What I am trying to do**:

1. Set a Timeout for the request
2. Catch Related Exception for the timeout for the request
3. Get the response code for the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question really has nothing to do with MvvmCross, Xamarin or Android, since you're using the same HTTP client you would in any .NET application. Nevertheless, `HttpClient` has a `Timeout` property which you can set to ensure your requests time out after a certain interval. I've changed `GetStringAsync` to `GetAsync`, since `GetAsync` will throw a `TaskCanceledException` if the request times out, which you can catch and handle. `GetStringAsync` would handle the timeout internally, and you wouldn't be able to catch it. I've rewritten your method to achieve that (this example has a 30-second timeout), as well as assign the status code to a variable for you to use:

```
public async Task<StellaData> GetStellConfigData()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000)
        })
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(Constants.mUrl));

            HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;

            var myItems = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StellaData>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            return myItems;
        }

    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException tcex)
    {
        // The request timed out
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you [+1] ... Also How to convert:
`system.net.http.httpresponemessage to system.io.stream`
.
Because at `var myItems = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StellaData>(response);` getting the error

Comment: I've edited my answer to cover the deserialisation of the awaited response string. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 2):

This class can be refactored to reuse the client instead of creating a new instance for each request. Set the time-out on the client when initialized.

```
public class RestService : IRestService {
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static RestService() {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Constants.DefaultTimeOut);
    }

    public async Task<StellaData> GetStellConfigData() {
        try {                
            //Add the API
            using(var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(Constants.mUrl))) {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<StellaData>();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats more efficient and clean way.